# mongodb update Unexpected token

Tags: mongodb, express, reactjs

I try to update my collection in MongoDB.

```js
[ { _id: 5811cc62a50998a59193d4c0,
    film: 
     { id: '2',
       title: 'Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales ',
       year: '2017',
       quality: 'HDrip',
       stars: 'John Depp, Orlando Bloom, Javier Bardem, Kaya Scodelario, Brenton Thwaites',
       Show: true },
    Show: false },
  { _id: 5811d693e4d24a0a69e8c12f,
    film: 
     { id: 5,
       title: 'Doctor Strange',
       year: '2016',
       quality: 'Blu-ray',
       stars: 'Benedict Cumberbatch, Chiwetel Ejiofor, Rachel McAdams, Benedict Wong, Mads Mikkelsen',
       Show: true } },
  { _id: 5811d9e884efe15a708a8f1d,
    film: 
     { id: 6,
       title: 'Hacksaw Ridge',
       year: '2016',
       quality: 'DVDrip',
       stars: 'Teresa Palmer, Andrew Garfield, Vince Vaughn, Hugo Weaving, Sam Worthington',
       Show: true } } ]
```

Here I wanna get to item 'Show' in 'film' in any object of array.

I've written:

```js
 db.wl.update({query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body._id)},
  update: {$set: {film.$.Show: req.body.newShow}}
  })
```

But in result I get this mistake:
[image]

Erlier I try with '.0.' instead of '.$.' and just with dot. 
It still doesn't work.

Comment: it's `{$set: {"film.$.Show": req.body.newShow}`, between quotes

Comment: it still doesn't change anything

Comment: what do you mean? The error should be different at least

Comment: Oh, it is. On server is everything fine. But when I check my objects that have returned in browser console, this value hasn't changed, but should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the query is correct and is returning the object you want to update. Also, update is an asynchronous method, and from the code you've showed, you are not implementing the callback. Should be something like:

```
db.wl.update({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body._id)},
  {$set: {"film.Show": req.body.newShow}}
  , function(err, res) {
      if (err){
          console.warn(err.message);
      }else{
          console.log(res);
          //do something
      }
  });)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is everything ok with query, but thanks for idea

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in `db.wl.update`. Below is how i ve solved it.

```
db.wl.update(
    {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body._id)},
    {$set: {"film.Show": req.body.newShow}}
  )
```

With it everything work fine. Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: wow that's correct, missed this. I'll update my answer too so it won't mislead anyone